# How to design solution in ASP.NET to batch insert request data to Azure Table Storage

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-table-storage

I'm designing a solution that needs to record web request data (billions of requests daily) and I want to store this data permanently in Azure Table Storage. Given the volume of inserts/updates, transactional costs are a concern so I would like to bulk insert into table storage.

This is a challenge in ASP.Net. If I were to do this in-proc, I would be temporarily recording the data to memory cache or similar and then periodically (lets say every second) batch inserting them to Table Storage. 
But this has its own drawbacks, namely memory concerns due to the requirement of storing the data until its flushed to table storage. 
Using other solutions like sending the data to a queue (e.g Azure Queue or Service Bus) and having another process do the batching does not avoid the transactional costs, as the same costs are imposed on Azure Queue and Service Bus).

Are there any best practices/design patterns that address this challenge that would be applicable to a solution that would allow me to minimize the transactional costs?

Comment: This is fairly broad, with no right answer (so, off-topic). Having said that: You'll want to look at your storage-write frequency, and make sure your writes will fit into the storage table partition (2K/sec) and account (20K/sec) transaction limits (which can be somewhat dealt with via entity group transactions within a partition). How you queue things up is really a matter of opinion - lots of approaches (including ones you've mentioned).

Comment: Maybe you should try [Azure Event Hubs][https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-overview/]. It is designed to ingest millions of events per second. But it does not solve your cost problem.